# For some natural number $N$,the number of positive integral $'x'$ satisfying the equation is?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

> For some natural number $N$,the number of positive integers $'x'$
>   satisfying the equation  $1!+2!+3!+...+(x!)=(N)^2$

Please give some hints.

Comment: I think I remember that it is known that the only solutions are $x=1$ and $x=3$ (if we allow the empty sum, also $x=0$). But I do not know how it can be proven. Bertrands Postulate might help.

Comment: @Peter Bertrands Postulate seems to be a scary name :-P..btw i don't think it should be very tough as it is from my high school textbook exercise

Comment: Bertrands Postulate is simple : It states that for every integer $n>1$, there is a prime $p$ with $n<p<2n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly $(x,N)= (1,1)$ and $(3,3)$ satisfy the equation.

Now up until $x=4$, the LHS is $1+2+6+24=33$ and after $x=4$, $k!=10l$ is a multiple of $10$.
Therefore for all $x$ greater than equal to $5$ the sum is of the form $10p+3$ which can never be perfect square.
Therefore only 2 ordered pairs exist.

Comment: So easy and without Bertrand! Well done !

Comment: thanks, what is the Bertrand postulate anyay?

Comment: Look at my comment above.

Comment: I'm not able to view it

Comment: Is it possible to prove 10p+3 cannot be perfect square?

Comment: That is easy. The ending digit of a square must be $0,1,4,5,6$ or $9$. Just verify the squares of the numbers $1$ to $10$ and consider $(10x+y)^2=100x^2+20xy+y^2=10k+y^2$

Comment: @Peter That's great!

Comment: @raghav Now you should have enough reputation to see my comment :)

Comment: yeah, I do! .I just joined today.